# Store data in Pivot table in many to many relationship in laravel crud

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, crud

I am trying to store `product_id` and `supplier_id` in pivot table `product_supplier` but it is not getting displayed in the database pivot table.

ProductController

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('manymany.product.index',compact('products'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $suppliers = Supplier::all();
        return view('manymany.product.create',compact('suppliers'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->create([
            'name'=>$request->productname,
            'detail'=>$request->detail
        ]);
        $product->suppliers()->attach($request->suppliers);
        return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('successs','Product added successfully!!!');
    }
```

Product Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name','detail'];

    public function suppliers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class, 'product_supplier','product_id','supplier_id');
    }
```

SupplierController

```
public function index()
    {
        $suppliers=Supplier::all();
        return view('manymany.supplier.index',compact('suppliers'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('manymany.supplier.create',compact('products'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $supplier = new Supplier;
        $supplier->create([
            'name'=>$request->suppliername,
            'contact'=>$request->contact,
            'email'=>$request->email
        ]);
        $supplier->products()->attach($request->products);
        return redirect()->route('supplier.index')->with('successs','Supplier added successfully!!!');
    }
```

Supplier Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name','contact','email'];

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_supplier','supplier_id','product_id');
    }
```

product_supplier migration

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('product_supplier', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('supplier_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with store value of that record and then use that id in attach method.
Here is Updated code you can try..

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $supplier = new Supplier;
    $supplier = $supplier->create([
         'name'=>$request->suppliername,
         'contact'=>$request->contact,
         'email'=>$request->email
    ]);
    $supplier->products()->attach($request->products);
    return redirect()->route('supplier.index')->with('successs','Supplier added successfully!!!');
 }
```

Comment: still not getting it in `product_supplier` table

Comment: Are you getting any error ,can you please share your , request data which you are passing ?

Comment: No errors and I am getting data in the form input and the requested data is mentioned in controller store method.

Comment: Is $request->suppliers type is array and container valid supplier id which are present in supplier table ?.

Comment: yes `$request->suppliers is array

Comment: no wait the `$request->supplier` is null array why so ? I just `dd($request->supplier)`

Comment: @PranavSompura try to use ```$reques->input('suppliername');```